# Why Laravel stores only the last file when I upload several files at the time?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I like to upload multiple files at once.

Frontend Vue / Vuetify:

```
                                    <v-file-input
                                        v-model="files"
                                        id="files"
                                        ref="files"
            
                                        multiple
                                        label="Bild oder Datei hinzufügen"
                                        @change="handleFilesUpload"
                                    >

    export default {
        name: "HeaderNotesModal",
        data: () => ({
            media: [],
            files: [],
        }),

        methods: {

            submit () {
                this.$refs.form.validate()
                if (this.valid) {
                    this.store({
                        payload: {
                            title: this.title,
                            body: this.body
                        },
                        context: this
                    }).then(() => {
                        if (this.errors.length === 0) {
                            this.title = ''
                            this.body = ''
                            this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
                            this.form = false
                        }
                        if( this.files.length !== 0 ){
                            this.addMedia({ 'media': this.formData})
                        }
                    })
                }

            },

            handleFilesUpload(e){
                var self = this;
                var files = this.files;
                if(files.length > 0){
                    for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++){
                        self.formData.append("file[]", files[i], files[i].name);
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchNotes()
        }
    }


export const addMedia = ({ state, commit }, { media}) => {
    
    return axios.post(`/api/notes/${state.note.id}/media`, media, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
    
}
```

Backend Laravel:

```
    public function store(Request $request, Note $note)
    {
        if($request->hasfile('file'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('file') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $file->move(storage_path('uploads'), $name);
                $data[] = $name;
            }
        }
        return 'success';
    }
```

When I upload multiple files, it stores only the last file.

I have tried several possible things, but I didn't found the error.

I tried to change the frontend, then also the backend.

I tried with formData and without.

I tried with several file names.

All without success

var_dump `return var_dump($request->file('file'));`

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/home/vagrant/code/7aio/app/Http/Controllers/Note/NoteMediaController.php:27:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>object</b>(<i>Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile</i>)[<i>392</i>]
      <i>private</i> 'test' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
      <i>private</i> 'originalName' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'bgvqm7da.png'</font> <i>(length=12)</i>
      <i>private</i> 'mimeType' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'image/png'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
      <i>private</i> 'error' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
      <i>protected</i> 'hashName' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
      <i>private</i> 'pathName' <small>(SplFileInfo)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'/tmp/phpIIfLwD'</font> <i>(length=14)</i>
      <i>private</i> 'fileName' <small>(SplFileInfo)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'phpIIfLwD'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>object</b>(<i>Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile</i>)[<i>372</i>]
      <i>private</i> 'test' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
      <i>private</i> 'originalName' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Screenshot at Apr 27 07-35-08.png'</font> <i>(length=33)</i>
      <i>private</i> 'mimeType' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'image/png'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
      <i>private</i> 'error' <small>(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
      <i>protected</i> 'hashName' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
      <i>private</i> 'pathName' <small>(SplFileInfo)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'/tmp/phpdRhiD1'</font> <i>(length=14)</i>
      <i>private</i> 'fileName' <small>(SplFileInfo)</small> <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'phpdRhiD1'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
</pre>
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$request->file('file')` contains all files? I am not sure if you are overwriting the file with `self.formData.append("file", files[i], files[i].name);` instead of `self.formData.append("file[]", files[i], files[i].name);`, changing `"file"` to `"file[]"`

Comment: I changed the code as you wrote. I edited the question. You can see the var_dump. Two files are in the request, but only one is stored.

Comment: Could you dump and verify that the names that are generated for the files are unique, depending on how fast the script executes, it might create the same value for `time()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the doc (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads)

> the move method may be used to rename or move an existing file to a
>   new location:

So by doing: `$file->move(storage_path('uploads'), $name);` it won't achieve what you are looking for.

You may instead use;

```
    foreach($request->file('file') as $file)
    {
        $name = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->store('uploads');
        $data[] = $name;
    }
```

Comment: With `time()` it doesn't work. But the rest of the code I will use.

Comment: Alrighty, let me know - if it solves your problem, please don't forget to accept the answer 